# Haskell, how to convert ADT to String?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

here is my ADT:

```
data Tree a = Val Integer
            |Tree a
            |Variable a
```

I have two questions:

Question 1: use *Tree String* type to represent some trees?

Question 2: define a function for converting a tree, an element of the datatype *Tree String* to string: *showTree::Tree String -> String*

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your questions. Can you clarify?

Comment: I have the Tree datatype, question is to use Tree String type for representing some trees.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With respect to your second question, coverting a tree into a string, just derive `Show` and use the `show` function:

```
data Tree a = Val Integer
            | Tree a
            | Variable a
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

showTree :: (Show a) => Tree a -> String
showTree = show
```

I don't understand your first question, so I'm just going to talk a bit in hopes that something I say helps you.

Understand that your "tree" data type is not really a tree at all, it's just a sum data type that can be instantiated by an integer or some type that matches the type variable, `a`.  The second constructor, `Tree`, is actually not making your data type recursive - its just a constructor name in the same way `Variable` is a constructor name.  I think you probably wanted to have subtrees (by using `Tree` as a type, not a constructor) - so let's define your type as:

```
data Tree a = Val Integer
            | Branch (Tree a) (Tree a)
            | Variable a
```

Now you have a constructor named `Branch` that has a left and a right sub-tree.  If your variables are supposed to be `String`s then you certainly can use `Tree String` to represent this:

```
myTree :: Tree String
myTree =
    let leftBranch = Variable "x"
        rightBranch = Branch (Val 3) (Variable "y")
    in Branch leftBranch rightBranch
```